# Is there a way to set a listener to a field changing in android to update a TextView?

Tags: android, textview, listeners

I want to set a listener in android so that I know when my field changes (an integer); and to update a textview upon it's change...

Not sure how to go about this?

Is it even possible?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that? If **you** or **your method**  change your field, why can't it just call `setText(..)` on a `TextView`? In such case there's no need to introduce a listener, it would be overkill

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for onTextChanged, maybe?
Step 1:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
 int before, int count) {
///code
}
```

PD: Google is quite clever, you should ask him more often. He would be pleased to help.

Comment: The thing is; I am not listening for the TextView to change; I am listening for an integer field (int someNumber) to change that is in the class header. And when it does change; to set the TextView with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextWatcher on EditText. Check the below example

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // Here you will get complete text from edittext after text changed
            // do your task
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // Here you will get complete text from edittext before text changed
            // do your task
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Here you can check 's' is number or not. It it is number you can set that number to your textview with your own logic
            // do your task
        }
    });
```

Hope this will help you.

**Don't forget to Vote Up :)**

Cheerz

Comment: The thing is; I am not listening for the TextView to change; I am listening for an integer field (int someNumber) to change that is in the class header. And when it does change; to set the TextView with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "change that is in the class header" ?

Comment: read the whole sentence:  I am listening for an integer field (int someNumber) to change that is in the class header.

Comment: i.e. the integer field changes value somewhere in my code.